# How much time to charge a laptop the first time if it's at 0%

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

Recently I bought a replacement battery for my laptop. The battery was completely discharged (0%). I was nor able even to boot the BIOS.

1. The battery should not be at least at 40%, to avoid wearing?
2. I read on the HP website that the battery of a laptop should be charged for 24h the fist time. Is this true?
3. I usually use the laptop plugged in. Doesn't the recharge stop if the battery is fully charged? If so, the second point is wrong?

The laptop is a Dell Latitude 5480 and the new battery is a 7.6V, 68WH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced batteries before. 12 Hours is normally enough if you need to get going, but allowing it to charge the first time for 24 hours will not harm anything. This assumes, of course, that the battery is physically good (will accept a charge).

The charging circuit will not overcharge the battery.

After the first full charge use the battery normally:  Use the battery down to about 30 percent and then charge to full. Disconnect and repeat this cycle in normal use.

That works very well for me.

Comment: The last point is bad advice if you want to prolong your battery life. You should ideally not charge your battery to more then 80% for prolonged periods. https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries dies stats on li ion batteries. The outcomes are similar (but different numbers) for all lithium polymer batteries.

Comment: There is no issue in charging to full if you then disconnect (as I noted) . Only if always plugged in do you need to keep at 80%.  I added a very most clarification to be crystal clear.

Comment: @davidgo About 80%, someone says that manufacturesers already caps the max limit to not ruin the battery. Is this true?

Comment: If a laptop is use plugged in at all times, then charging to just 80% is generally considered to to a good idea. If you charge up, disconnect, use down to about 30%, charge up and repeat the cycle then full charge does not harm the battery

Comment: Also, the manufacturer I use does not cap or limit the charge level. I do not think limiting charge is a general practice. There is battery software from the manufacturers to limit charge level. I use this on the machine I leave plugged in all the time.

Comment: (I disagree about charging to 100% not putting stress in battery - certainly this is less then holding it at 100% but it is still  very significant.) Limiting charge is a common practice - but of-course interferes with planned obsolescence. I'm a Dell fanboi, and all my Dell laptops since 2016 have this functionality. I'm pretty sure my 2014 one does to. Its on many HP, Microsoft, Samsung, Lenovo, Acer, Sony, MSI models.

Comment: According to https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries "  
Most Li-ions charge to 4.20V/cell, and every reduction in peak charge voltage of 0.10V/cell is said to double the cycle life. For example, a lithium-ion cell charged to 4.20V/cell typically delivers 300–500 cycles. If charged to only 4.10V/cell, the life can be prolonged to 600–1,000 cycles; 4.0V/cell should deliver 1,200–2,000 and 3.90V/cell should provide 2,400–4,000 cycles"

Answer (score 1):

You should send back that battery - if it comes to you in a flat state it has been damaged. (It could be a manufacturing defect or neglect, either way its taken a hit on its lifespan)

1. Yes, the battery should be about 40% charged when received. Anythin g below 20% is not good and below 5% is not OK.
2. "That depends" - its likely that this relates to calibration - ie accurately advising his long a charge will last (not how full it is - which is tied to voltage). Keeping a battery at 100% charge is the second worst state for it (but not as bad as below 5%) - if you do do this, avoid keeping it at 100% for a prolonged period.
3. Charging does "stop" at 100% charged and you shouldn't be able to overcharge the battery. Keeping it in a high state of charge does cause stress to it. Most Dell (and many other) laptops allow you to set a lower maximum charge in the BIOS which can greatly prolong the battery life at the expense if runtime when unplugged.